# Making a simple email application

Tags: android, email

So the story is that basically, I'm making a very simple app so that my place of employment can send the closing logs every night with ease. I have all of the text boxes to enter the information, and then at the bottom there is a checkbox and submit like so..

[image]

There is a template for the email that we edit manually every night, and basically I want to take all of the information received in the text boxes (all have their own ID, etc.) and plug it into the email template that I currently have - and send it to the emails of the employees (6 people).

Can someone lead me in the right direction, or show me how I would go about this problem?

MainActivity.java

```
package savo.nicholas.bestb;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

I've constructed a bunch of these to get the values from the form. I'm looking to plug these values into a pre-formatted email and send them.

```
public EditText getGm() //$ of GM
{
    return (EditText)findViewById(R.id.gm);
}
```

Thanks! 
Nick

Comment: the easiest would be to use one of those intents: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#ComposeEmail to trigger the existing email composer with the formatted email that you have. The user will just have to press "send" in the email app.

Comment: I've made progress - I made an intent for the actual email, but at this time I'm trying to build the email to be sent and filled in with the boxes in the app.

I updated the OP. How do I build a pre-formatted message and substitute all the variables into it?

Comment: `a pre-formatted message`. That is called a template. You can make it the way you want. And google for examples.

Comment: String place = "Boston"; String template = "Todays work in {place} started at {starttime}; template.replace("{place}", place);.

Comment: @greenapps cool!! That makes sense.  The only real big hiccup that I have is the fact that there’s literally like 30 variables to plug into a large email. This is also doable?

Comment: Yes pretty normal for a template.

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/MessageFormat.html